# Existence of sequences of natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $x \in [0, 1)$ does there exists a sequence of natural numbers $a_n, b_n$ such that the sequence $a_n/b_n$ converges to $x$.

Comment: Yes, since the rationals are dense in $[0,1).$ Proof is not difficult, and you may find it enjoyable, no need to use the "dense subset" concept though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, here's a (somewhat formal) proof without using the idea of density as a commenter mentioned. Since $x\in[0,1)$, it has a decimal representation $0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$. Let
$$a_n=\sum_{i=1}^na_i10^{n-i}$$
and
$$b_n=10^n.$$
Then $a_n/b_n$ is just the decimal number $0.a_1a_2\ldots a_n$ so clearly $|x-a_n/b_n|\leq10^{-n}$.

*Please note:* Some people define $\mathbb N$ to not include zero. If you're one of these people, to account for the $x=0$ case, you can easily pick something like $a_n=1$ and $b_n=n$. To deal with the case where $0\neq x=0.0000a_ka_{k+1}a_{k+2}\ldots$, shift the sequence over to start at the $k$th term.

Answer (score 2):

let $b_n = n$ and $a_n = \lfloor b_n x \rfloor$. Then ${a _n \over b_n} \to x$.

To see this, note that
$a_n \le b_n x < a_n+1$ and so ${a _n \over b_n} \le x \le {a _n \over b_n}+{1 \over b_n}$, in particular
$|x-{a _n \over b_n}| \le {1 \over b_n}$.

There is nothing special about the sequence $b_n = n$, any non zero
sequence diverging to $+\infty$ will do.